# How to take array of numbers and return array with numbers doubled?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that will take an array of numbers and return an array with those numbers doubled. For example `1, 2, 3` and return should be `2, 4, 6`.

This is what I have so far:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function doubleNumbers(numbers) {
    return numbers =  1 * 2 + ", " + 2 * 2 + ", " + 3 * 2;
}

console.log(doubleNumbers(numbers));
```

This is putting out the correct answer in the console, although I have a feeling something is off.

When I change the `const numbers=[1, 2, 3]` to any other number, I'm still getting 2,4,6. Which leads me to believe `function doubleNumbers` isn't pulling the numbers from the array, only multiplying the numbers I have in `return numbers`.

Comment: All your values are hardcoded "1*2". Check out the map method for Arrays. I have the feeling this is a homework question, this needs more work.

Comment: `A solution could be:
 
    const numbers = [1, 4, 3];
    
    function doubleNumbers(numbers) {
        return numbers.map(n => n * 2).join(', ');
    }
    
    console.log(doubleNumbers(numbers)); ` But more important is to go and learn the fundamentals of JS

Comment: @strattonn Yes It is. It's 1 question from an exercise list. Notice how I have worked on the problem myself and have tried other solutions as well. Not asking for the answer and clearly it needs more work, that's why I'm here to get help. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function doubleNumbers(numbers) {
    return numbers.map(x => x * 2);
}

console.log(doubleNumbers(numbers));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This worked perfectly! One thing I'm trying to understand better is ```(x => x * 2);```

From my understanding .map is creating a new array and then the arrow function ```=>``` is multiplying each number in the array by 2? Is this correct? And if so, what does the X represent?

Comment: Yes, it creates a new array by doubling each element of the original array. `x` is the first parameter of the callback, which is the original array element value to transform.

Answer (score 0):

Do like:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3], doubles = numbers.map(n=>n*2);
console.log(doubles);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have 2 questions. What is the blank array ```double= [ ]``` for? AND how would I list those numbers on the same line, instead of underneath each other?

Comment: I was assigning an empty Array in my previous example. That's just how the `console` displays things. You could do like `SomeElement.textContent = doubles.join(', ');` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `for` instead of `map()`:

```
function numbers(arr){
  let newArr = [];
  for(let i of arr){
    newArr.push(i * 2);
  }
  return newArr;
}
```